# What type of main propellant valves are being used in Rutherford Engine?

Tags: propulsion, plumbing, cross-feed

I am confused about the main fuel and oxidizer valves used in Rutherford engine by Rocket Lab's Electron Launch Vehicle (as shown in video link attached). It looks like angle valves but I don't see any actuation mechanism. Can anyone help?

Video: [Rocket Lab's "Rutherford Engine" in Vimeo](https://vimeo.com/124891416)

> Rocket Lab’s flagship engine, the 4,600 lbf Rutherford, is a turbo-pumped LOX/RP-1 engine specifically designed for the Electron Launch Vehicle.
>
> Rutherford adopts an entirely new electric propulsion cycle, using electric motors to drive its turbopumps, and is the first oxygen/hydrocarbon engine to use 3D printing for all primary components.